# How to redirect users from WP login to custom URL via a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I built a Wordpress plugin which creates a custom login for Wordpress users. but now I want to redirect every user who wants to login to my custom login. I want to invoke that change from my plugin.

I saw some solutions with add_action method to be put into the theme's function.php but how to do that programmatically from the plugin.

I'm a noobie in WP Plugin dev, code snippets are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following code to your plugin '.php' file:

```
/**
 * Redirect user after successful login.
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */

 function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

This would then redirect people back to the page they logged in from if they are have admin priviliges or otherwise back to the homepage. You can adapt this as needed to suit your redirection needs.

Or if you want to specifically redirect all users to a fixed page / uri you could use this simpler version:

```
function your_function() {
// your code
wp_redirect("http://yourdomain.com/your-page") ;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
```

You can find more info in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect).

Comment: well you got me wrong, I need to redirect users before they login, ie, when they enter site.com/wp-login.php url.

Comment: Then you need to explain the scenario completely.